# make Xvfb listen only on local ip

Tags: security, xorg, vnc, tcp, xvfb

to use graphical software even on my debian based systems without graphic cards (or in addition to its main graphic) i use the virtual frame buffer x server Xvfb. I am starting it with a little bash script called startvx using screen. here is the content of the script:

```
treaki@hostname:~/bin$ cat startvx 
!/bin/bash
#starts a virtual x server with local listening vnc server and openbox to run apps without graphic cards (or in addition to its main graphic)
#runn it like this:
#screen -dmS vx startvx
Xvfb :1&
export DISPLAY=:1
openbox &
x11vnc -localhost -forever -shared
treaki@hostname:~/bin$
```

my problem is, as you can see in the next posting, that the port for the x server is open to the network. That is not a big problem because there are no permissions set for accessing the x server unsing network but i possible would like to keep my x server running for a secret (avoid giving out to much information) without having to use the linux firewall. So my question is:
how can i modify that script to get Xvfb listen only to my local network?

```
$ sudo nmap -v -A 192.168.xxx.xxx

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-12-20 18:46 CET
[...]
Discovered open port 6001/tcp on 192.168.xxx.xxx
[...]
6001/tcp open  X11     (access denied)
[...]
$ #i would like to remove this open port 6001 without setting a firewall
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `-nolisten tcp` to the command like:

```
Xvfb -nolisten tcp :1&
```

Unfortunately there is nothing written in the [man page](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) about it.